# Kerberos authentication using mod_auth_kerb against ActiveDirectory and multiple Realms

Tags: active-directory, apache2, kerberos

Our environment looks like this:

- we've got a forest of ActiveDirectory servers that trust each other.
- we've got a Linux Apache with mod_auth_kerb that authenticates against the "main" AD server.

For some combinations of clients & domains, we get the following error message:

```
krb5_get_init_creds_password() failed: KRB5 error code 68
```

Googling says this error:

```
is being returned by Active Directory because your users are
attempting to obtain a Kerberos TGT for a realm that
is not hosted on the server to which they are authenticating.
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add **all** necessary Realms/KDCs into your krb5.conf. GSSAPI cannot obtain a ticket for an unknown realm.
The above examplee works perfectly with gssapi in our forest env.

To ease the configuration work, you may configure your `krb5.conf` to query DNS to lookup the KDCs. This is what Windows does.

Comment: But we only have the main AD in our krb5 config, and many other realms work out of the box. I can't figure out what the difference between them is. Also, the DNS lookup thing is new to me - is there a good introduction somewhere?

Comment: Share your `krb5.conf` and all names of the domains in the forest. You may obfuscate them. Consult [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man5/krb5.conf.5heimdal.html) man page for `dns_lookup_kdc`. This is how you can perform a KDC lookup per DNS manually: `host -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.DnsDomainName`. See [Microsoft's reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx).